# Given $n=pq=a^2+b^2$, can we factor $n$?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, number-theory, factoring

Just to be clear, $a$ and $b$ are known, while $p$ and $q$ are unknown prime numbers, both congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. Can we design an efficient algorithm to retrieve $p$ and $q$?

It is a known result that $p$ and $q$ can be written as a sum of two squares in exactly one way, and $n$ can be written in exactly two ways.
If $p=x^2+y^2$, $q=z^2 +t^2$ then 
$a^2+b^2=(x^2+y^2)(z^2+t^2)=(xz+yt)^2 + (xt-yz)^2=(xt+yz)^2+(xz-ty)^2$

So we get two possible systems of equations involving $a,b,x,y,z,t$, but it's not obvious how to solve the systems in general.

Comment: I don't think the answer is known. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1828992/1277) for a related problem. If you could factor $n$ given $a,b$, this would show that finding $a,b$ is (probably) hard, but that is apparently not known.

Comment: Thanks!  For the future: we'd prefer that you avoid "EDIT:" -- see https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: I don't think the system of quadratic equations helps, unless there is some additional structure that I'm missing; in general solving quadratic equations over the integers is believed to be hard.  So I suspect Yuval's comment might be the best we can say right now.  Perhaps someone else will have further insights.